# Android USB ATTACH open app again even if the app is already running

Tags: java, android, usb

My app is trying to do something with an external USB device. In the Manifest I have added the following lines of code:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>

<meta-data
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
    android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```

Now when the USB is attached, a prompt for me to choose which app to open is shown. The chosen app will be opened after I click onto it. If I check the "remember defaults" checkbox, my app will be automatically opened when the USB is attached. However, if I open the app first manually then plug in the USB device, it seems another instance of the app is launched and my app crashed. Any ideas?